# How do I change A Custom data attribute that have multiple key value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM

```
    <body id='bodeh' class="loading" data-layout-mode="horizontal" data-layout='{"mode": "light", "width": "fluid", "menuPosition": "fixed", "topbar": {"color": "light"}, "showRightSidebarOnPageLoad": false}'>
```

I wanted to change the data-layout 'mode' to dark with Jquery.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. e.g.

```
const val = $(document.body).data("layout");
val.mode = "dark";
$(document.body).data("layout", val);
```

See it work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2eub38j5/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are writing JSON inside `data-layout` so one solution is to parse that JSON into an object modify it and then stringify it and set the data attribute. We could write a simple function for that:

```js
const useElemForData = (elem, dataAttr) => {
  return {
    setData(value) {
      elem.dataset[dataAttr] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getData() {
      return JSON.parse(elem.dataset[dataAttr]);
    }
  };
};
```

Now if you want to use that with `data-layout` and the body, you can do this:

```js
const layoutData = useElemForData($("body"), "layout");

layoutData.setData({ ...layoutData.getData(), mode: "light" });
```